# Hide or Mask Connection String

Tags: excel, oracle, security, connection-string

Hoping someone can help. I have an excel file that I have connected to an oracle database, in the connection string it is showing the username & password. Does anyone know of a way for this not to show or mask it in any way? I have been clicking around excel and looking up ways for the past hour but cannot find anything that works.